The run_duration column from the msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory returns negative values
From time to time the run_duration column from the msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory returns a negative value for one of the jobs see example below.

The job is successfully finished at the time of the query. Any idea what could be a reason for it?
We are discussing SQL 2019 (15.0.4322.2). So far this has happened only 2 or three times in the last couple of days with just a single job executed with the 5m frequency. The job has been executed without this issue for months. No other job shows this behavior, but hard to say whether it is a rule...
This is a user created job. It causes just a minor trouble with the monitoring of the long running jobs (I have already handled the exception it causes). I am just wondering what could cause this behavior.

One possibility is the duration is negative because the system clock was adjusted during the job's execution.
SQL Server uses a frankly daft integer representation for dates, times, and durations in these tables. I suppose the algorithm used to convert a duration to the integer encoding isn't set up to handle negative durations.

You are right, the time has been adjusted on the server during the execution. I was able to proof this from the Windows Event Log (Get-EventLog -LogName Security -InstanceId 4616).
